# Sending/receiving a continuous stream of data using SIM7600

Tags: stm32, gsm, simcom

I have a SIM7600EI connected to an STM32 controller over UART. I am able to send HTTP POST requests for small chunks of data using AT commands. Currently, I want to send a continuous stream of data using the module. However I'm wondering how to do this, considering that each AT command routine can take up to a couple of hundred milliseconds. Other GSM libraries like tinyGSM are also blocking and takes a while to read and verify the AT command responses.

How, in that case, can I handle a data stream (considering that I'll have to transfer multiple chunks, and so will need multiple HTTP requests). How are GSM modules like this interfaced with controllers in such a way that seamless high-speed (eg: live image streaming) data transmission is possible. How can I build complex applications like web servers using these modules?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it should go with the use of the microphone input and speaker output (not shure if there is one) on Maduino Zero 4G LTE board. You can initiate a call/activate sound reception/sound playback using AT and they stay listening. You need to connect an encoder to the microphone input and a decoder on speaker output on your side-and vice versa.
Maybe i am wrong, but it would be worth a try.